# Newbie question: database for a language school

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm building a database to create lessons for an online language school. I'm not an expert but this is what I came up with. Each lesson will be composed by "blocks" that can be pretty much anything (language presentation, listening, etc) that can contain some media. I would like to know if at a first look it makes sense or there is something that looks out of place. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Smacks of "over-normalization".

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: I red this https://lemire.me/blog/2010/12/02/over-normalization-is-bad-for-you/ and now it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for that link!  You might have eventually realized some of it when you started to write `SELECTs`.  I often say "I can't judge a schema without seeing the `SELECTs`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question - you're essentially asking us to comment on an entire system design. Speaking from experience, that's virtually impossible to do on a first pass - you have some tables and you're going to put data in them. Great.

Whether it will "hang together" as a coherent system once you start working with and querying it is another kettle of fish altogether!

In order to help you, I Googled "open source language school software" and the first non-advertisement was [this](https://gibbonedu.org/) which might either serve as a basis for your own system or you might decide to abandon the dev route and just use it. There are a shedload of other interesting links there. You could also visit [this page](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) and search for the word "school" - there's goodies there also!

As I said above, you're asking for a comment on an entire system before it's even been written - this is more of a "I'm developing a system, I have these tables with structures x, y and z and I'm having a problem with doing a, b or c" kind of site.

Your question requires more of a position paper than a simple answer. I know myself from having developed systems that it's **above all else** an **iterative** process and that you'll go down many roads which will turn into dead ends for your particular requirements (and that's fine!), but to ask **anybody** to just cast an eye over a series of table definitions and even be able to comment on how well they'll work is basically impossible!

I suggest you look at the software from the Google and then move from there - if you can find programmes that meet (or come close to meeting) your requirements from the already existing F/LOSS (Free/Libre and Open Source) world, then great! The other great thing about F/LOSS is that you can adopt and adapt. HTH, and welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I understand my question was very broad and hard to answer. I'll check out the links you provided. I'll probably try to use this database while developing a "test" application and see what happens.

Comment: Best of luck - if you have more specific problems, don't hesitate to come back to us!

Comment: @devamat - Yes, test it out.  _But_ plan on doing a major overhaul of the schema before long.  That's part of the learning experience.